# Zero cost non-macro solution for calling a function in the correct order

Tags: c++

I have a code base where some common functions need to be called in order before and after some unique function

Eg:

```
common1();
common2();
unique();   // note: unique returns void but can have any number of arguments
common3();
common4();
```

A problem is, anytime a new `unique` is made, or anytime more `commonX` functions are added then every place in the code where this pattern is required has to be made to match.

One solution is to use a macro

```
#define DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY(unique_code_block) \
  common1();           \
  common2();           \
  unique_code_block    \
  common3();           \
  commont();           \

...

void someFunc1(arg1) {
  DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY({
    unique1(arg1);
  });
}

void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY({
    unique2(arg1, arg2);
  });
}
```

That works. The question is: Is there a non-Macro C++ way to do this with ZERO overhead **AND** discourage mistakes **AND** and not be overly verbose to use.

Note: if it's not obvious, the "not overly verbose" requirement means the functions I'm calling might have lots of parameters with very large types. Having to copy and paste the list of types = "overly verbose"

One solution I know of is something like this

```
class Helper {
  Helper() {
    common1();
    common2();
  }
  ~Helper() {
    common3();
    common4();
  }
}

void someFunc1(arg1) {
  Helper helper;
  unique1(arg1);
}

void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  Helper helper;
  unique2(arg1, arg2);
}
```

The problem with this solution IMO is it's seems easy to insert stuff unaware that you're doing it wrong

```
void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  Helper helper;
  doExtra1();     // bad
  unique2(arg1, arg2);
  doExtra2();     // bad
}
```

Like imagine that `common2` is `perfRecordStartTime` and `common3` is `perfRecordEndTime`. In that case you don't want anything extra before/after `unique2`.

You could argue the same issue with the macro

```
void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY({
    doExtra1();     // bad
    unique2(arg1, arg2);
    doExtra2();     // bad
  });
});
```

But rename `DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY` to say `TIME_FUNCTION` and `Helper` to `TimingHelper`

```
void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  TIME_FUNCTION({
    doExtra1();     // clearly bad
    unique2(arg1, arg2);
    doExtra2();     // clearly bad
  });
});
```

vs

```
void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  TimingHelper helper;
  doExtra1();     // bad?
  unique2(arg1, arg2);
  doExtra2();     // bad?
}
```

`TimingHelper` so doing magic stuff here. Maybe it's just an opinion but this helper pattern seems more error prone for this case than the macro pattern.

Is it also some possibly super tiny but non-zero cost calling into the Helper constructor/destructor vs the inline code of the macro?

Another is to use lambdas

```
template<typename Func>
void DoUniqueCorrectly(Func fn) {
  common1();
  common2();
  fn();
  common3();
  common4();
}

void someFunc1(arg1) {
  DoUniqueCorrectly([&]() {
    unique1(arg1);
  });
}

void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  DoUniqueCorrectly([&]() {
    unique2(arg1, arg2);
  });
}
```

The problem with this one is as far as I understand, lambdas are really building an object/tuple to hold on to references to the closed over arguments. To put another way it's almost like this

```
void someFunc2(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
  std::tuple<const type1&, const type2&> c = {arg1, arg2};
  DoUniqueCorrectly([&]() {
    unique2(std::get<0>(c), std::get<1>(c));
  });
}
```

So there is overhead of this tuple being initialized. Will that all be optimized out so the code will have the same overhead as the macro?

Let me add one more wrinkle. `uniqueX` can be a more complex function call. For example

```
void SomeClass::someFunc2(arg1, arg2) {
  DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY({
    getContext()->getThing()->unique2(arg1, arg2);
  });
}
```

Is there another solution?

PS: I get that if any overhead exists it's small. I still want to know if there is a zero overhead non-macro C++ way of doing this.

Comment: IMO I would personally use the template + lambda alternative you presented

Comment: A lambda does not at all use tuples or anything like that to store arguments. It is simply passing a reference to a constructor, storing the reference in an object and then calling a `operator()`. It is never possible to guarantee any kind of optimization behavior (not even for your macro version), but I am pretty sure in almost all cases where you would care, the lambda will compile to the same code as your original version.

Comment: What is the measured performance/memory impact of using the cleanest of your solutions?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt irrelevant. The question is not is the overhead small. The question is is their overhead at all. That it's small and I should ignore it is a reasonable  opinion but it's not the question I'm asking.

Comment: It might be zero, making it irrelevant. Concerning lambdas, you can tell them exactly what to capture.

Comment: If you dislike lambdas for some reason, a template can easily accept function pointers or even member (method) pointers as template arguments. So you could have `call_unique<&unique>(arg_for_unique, ...);` or the like.

Comment: @user17732522 "It is never possible to guarantee any kind of optimization behavior (not even for your macro version)", I get that. The thing is the macro version is arguably clearly not adding overhead. The others are adding potential overhead.

Comment: @gman The issue is that it is not clear how you want to measure "overhead". For example, if you use the original macro many times with `unique_code_block` being a function call to a `void()` function, then using the macro will produce a lot more instruction code than e.g. using the equivalent solution shown in Nikos Athanasiou's answer. This may have negative cache impacts that outweigh the additional single function calls that his solution would likely incur (since the compiler would avoid inlining if there are many calls to the same function if the function isn't short).

Comment: @user17732522 I understand those issues. Rather, the macro generates no extra code. The other solutions generate lots of extra code, which may or may not be optimized out. If they're generally optimized out that's great. If not I'd like to know. Lots of C++ is written under the assumption that when compiled the giant crazy template madness will turn into the zero code. One of C++'s major advertised features is its zero cost abstractions. With the macro it's clearly zero overhead. With the other solutions it's not, so I asked.

Comment: Why can you not use a simple function to abstract this pattern? From what you write it seems to me that you may be worrying whether your compiler will inline this function, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The decorator you presented can be easily extended to pass an arbitrary amount of arguments to your invocable:

```cpp
template<typename Func, class... Args>
void DoUniqueCorrectly(Func&& fn, Args&&... args) 
{
  common1();
  common2();
  std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  common3();
  common4();
}
```

then your use cases are called as:

```cpp
void someFunc1(arg1) { DoUniqueCorrectly(unique1, arg1); }
void someFunc2(arg1, arg2) { DoUniqueCorrectly(unique2, arg1, arg2); }
```

Everything forwarded to an inlinable function template (`DoUniqueCorrectly`). No extra or intermediate objects. Plus `std::invoke` will "generate" the correct call syntax for any type of callable (function pointers, lambdas, pointers to member functions etc etc) something that a MACRO doesn't do out of the box.

The ammended example (the wrinkle) would be called as

```cpp
DoUniqueCorrectly(&Thing::unique2, o.getContext()->getThing(), 1, 2);
```

i.e. pointer to member function called from object pointer. `std::invoke` has no problem.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54d6c338052d7f31)

Comment: I guess this wasn't in my original post (updated) but `unique` isn't always a simple plain stand alone function.

Comment: @gman If you mean `getContext()->getThing()->unique2(arg1, arg2);` this is exactly what `std::invoke` handles. I'll add an example

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as the correct answer but, I gotta say, it doesn't yet feel very intuitive. Especially that last call  I have to know the type of `getThing` in order to lookup the class method on the correct type where as that type doesn't appear anywhere in the calling code.

Comment: @gman That's always doable with `decltype(getThing())` but I guess the code would be even less intuitive. But if you have the callable directly (the `unique2` member function pointer) you don't even need that - just passing the target into `DoUniqueCorrectly` should do the work. There were some proposals around "unified function call syntax" which might simplify such instrumentation but I don't know the current state.

Comment: The amended example, using a pointer to member function, is not equivalent to the original.  `getContext` and `getThing` will be called before `common1` and `common2`, which is different than with the `DO_UNIQUE_CORRECTLY` macro.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak, agreed. Also I think I worded my question poorly. You'll see in the details of the question it's not a function I need inserted, it's a code block. The macro inserts a code block. The examples of solutions in the question mostly use a code block. This solution though only takes a function. I guess that's my fault for poor question wording, although I think the actual details make it clearer that code block is more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track there with the `Helper`. What you missed in your example is a scope block so the destructor isn't delayed:

```
{
    Helper helper;
    unique1(arg1);
}
```

As you say it's easy to insert other code into the block or forget the block entirely. One solution is to pass the unique function to the helper to execute. (or make it a function instead of an object):

```
Helper helper(&unique1, arg1);
helper_fn(&unique1, arg1);
```

Now the helper can run everything in the constructor (or the function) and nothing can be inserted. But it's not quite readable. And maybe you don't have a function to call by name but want to just run some code. You can do that with a lambda as you mentioned yourself:

```
Helper helper([&]() { some; code; });
```

That almost looks like other code constructs you have like `while (cond) { some; code; }`. Can we make it look even more like that? How about giving `Helper` an `operator+` that takes a `callable`? Then you can write:

```
Helper() + [&]() { some; code; }
```

For a last improvement I'm afraid we are back to using macros:

```
#define UNIQUE Helper() + [&]()

UNIQUE { some; code; }
```

I think that's the cleanest syntax you can get.

As for the overhead of the lambda: In simple cases the compiler should optimize it all away. In complex cases the overhead is tiny compared to the time the complex case takes. If it would take no time it would be a simple case the compiler optimizes. Try it and see how complex a case you have to make before it doesn't get optimized away. It's hard to predict what the compiler will do exactly, you have to test it.

For a full example of this method of hiding the lambda with proper exception handling look at [Declarative Control Flow](https://gist.github.com/mrvn/a8a4eddccece648e12239d255556431a). This actually delays code to be run at the end of the scope with the options to always run it or only on success or error. But you can easily adapt it to your use case and being able to handle errors in your UNIQUE helper might be invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a template-based solution where no additional parameters are passed (lambdas, `std::function`s or other) and everyting can be optimized down to “bare C“ by the compiler. It can be also easily extended and specialized for a `unique()` with a (non-`void`) return type if need be, but this is left out for the sake of brevity.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace {
using std::cout;
using std::forward;

void before() { cout << "before\n"; }
void after() { cout << "after\n"; }

void unique0() { cout << "unique0()\n"; }
void unique1(int a) { cout << "unique1(" << a << ")\n"; }
void unique2(int a, int b) { cout << "unique2(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n"; };

template <typename... A>
struct DoUniqueCorrectly {
  template <void (*U)(A...), typename... AA>
  static void unique(AA&&... args) {
    before();
    U(forward<AA>(args)...);
    after();
  }
};
}  // namespace

int main() {
  DoUniqueCorrectly<>::unique<&unique0>();
  DoUniqueCorrectly<int>::unique<&unique1>(3);
  DoUniqueCorrectly<int, int>::unique<&unique2>(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: So that works but it kind of ignores the "not overly verbose" requirement. The actual fucntions I'm using have large types and up to 11 arguments so this solution becomes very verbose.